# SQL filter 3 columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

Original table

[image]

I want to use SQL to filter out any records Type= 'B' or any records ID=1 or any records Color='red'.
I can filter out step by step.
Could I do it once.
I tried the `Where Type <> 'B' OR ID <> 1 OR Color <> 'red'` in SQL Server. But it doesn't work. Could someone help?
Thanks!

The expected result should be:

[image]

Comment: You want `AND` not `OR`.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Larnu, Thanks. I tired the AND before. but it didn't provide the expected result.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mre] - try creating a DBFiddle that shows that issue, because from what you have shown Larnu's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying, in SQL:

```
...
WHERE
 NOT (TYPE='B'
      OR ID=1
      OR Color='red')
```

or, applying the NOT operator to the parenthesised section:

```
...
WHERE
    TYPE<>'B'
    AND ID<>1
    AND Color<>'red'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try AND. I wonder what the evaluation order in where statement? Whether the 2nd filer is evaluated based on the result of 1st filter and so on?

Comment: An execution plan is generated based on a number of factors, including absence/presence of indices in those columns, and statistics on them (value distribution), and SQLServer might chose to use them in a different order then you might expect.